# Automapper and Naming Conventions

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm currently having an issue with Automapper and the LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention.

I'm trying to map two classes with represent adresses using a Profile.

Syntax as follows:

```
public class LowerCaseAddress
{
    public string address_line_1 { get; set; }
}

public class PascalCaseAddress
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
}

public class AddressReverseDataTypeProfile : Profile
{
    public AddressReverseDataTypeProfile()
    {
        SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();

        CreateMap<LowerCaseAddress, PascalCaseAddress>();
    }
}

public static IMapper AddressMapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;

    cfg.AddProfile<AddressReverseDataTypeProfile>();
}));

[Test]
public void ReverseMapTest()
{
    var inputAddress = new LowerCaseAddress()
    {
        address_line_1 =  "SAMPLE"
    };

    PascalCaseAddress sut = AddressMapper.Map<LowerCaseAddress, PascalCaseAddress>(inputAddress);

    var actualValue = sut.AddressLine1;

    Assert.AreEqual(actualValue, inputAddress.address_line_1);
}
```

Problem I'm having is that if my properties are address_line and AddressLine respectively - Automapper maps correctly - but as soon as we get integers on the end of the property name it fails.

We've got AddressLine1 - AddressLine10 on the source and target objects so this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: You need to write your own naming convention that does what you want.